# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out

Tags: android, ssl, file-upload

I am facing this issue only with perticular network ie.jio i know why it always throw time out error(may be because of server the handshake cant be completed) but cant find any solution .Works fine with every other network.
can any one help??
This is my code for uploading file :

```
public void uploadFile(Context context, File fileName) {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    try {
        flag = false;

        if (!client.isConnected()) {
         client.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPES);

            try
            {
                client.connect(FTP_HOST, 21);
                client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sc.init(null,trustAllCerts, new 
                java.security.SecureRandom());
                client.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

                client.login(FTP_USER,FTP_PASS);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);

            client.changeDirectory(UPLOAD_PATH);
            client.upload(fileName);
            flag = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            client.disconnect(true);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        flag = false;
    }
}



TrustManager[] trustAllCerts;

{
    trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }
    }};
}
```

Comment: If its just one network its more likely to be network setup than anything in your code.  Likely port 21 is blocked.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan is right, some network may block some ports, like 21.

Comment: what shud i do then?solution for this?

Comment: what will happen if i remove the  client.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPES);